# how to make a copy of object in javascript/vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working with js object, lets say:

```
items: [{text: 'text1', active: true},
{text: 'text1', active: true},
{text: 'text1', active: true}]
```

I want to make the copy of the object and make some changes with them in computed property like this way:

```
computed: {
   copyAndChange() {
      var itemsCopy = []
      itemsCopy = this.items
      for (var i=0; i<itemsCopy.length; i++) {
         itemsCopy[i].text = "something"
         console.log('text from items: ' + this.item[i])
         console.log('text from itemsCopy: ' + itemsCopy[i])
      }
      return itemsCopy
   }
}
```

This code gives me in console:

```
text from items: something
text from itemsCopy: something
text from items: something
text from itemsCopy: something
text from items: something
text from itemsCopy: something
```

(?) why? I expected:

```
This code gives me in console:
text from items: text1
text from itemsCopy: something
text from items: text1
text from itemsCopy: something
text from items: text1
text from itemsCopy: something
```

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are not creating a copy. You are assigning the reference to `this.items` to your `itemsCopy` array. Thus, you are later mutating the same array.

Create a copy with:

```
itemsCopy = this.items.slice();
```

The same issue applies with each object inside your array. In your loop, create a copy of the object:

```
var obj = Object.assign({}, itemsCopy[i]);
obj.text = "something";
itemsCopy[i] = obj;  //replace the old obj with the new modified one.
```

---

Demo:

```js
var items = [
  {text: 'text1', active: true},
  {text: 'text1', active: true},
  {text: 'text1', active: true}
];

function copyAndChange() {
  var itemsCopy = []
  itemsCopy = items.slice();
  for (var i=0; i<itemsCopy.length; i++) {
    var obj = Object.assign({}, itemsCopy[i]);
    obj.text = "something";
    itemsCopy[i] = obj;  //replace the old obj with the new modified one.
    console.log('text from items: ' + items[i].text)
    console.log('text from itemsCopy: ' + itemsCopy[i].text)
  }
  return itemsCopy
}

copyAndChange();
```

Comment: oh I see... but using `this.items.slice();` gives me the same result...

Comment: @gileneusz, sorry. Forgot that your array had objects. See my update above.

Comment: I'm checking...

Comment: this should work (as I can see in the snippet), but I've got the same wrong result in my computed property :/

Comment: are you sure you didn't forget anything? Did you do both the slice() and the Object.assign()?

Comment: oh, I miss slice(), now it works. The only difference is that in vue I've changed `itemsCopy = items.slice();` into 'this.items.slice();'. Thank you for help!

Comment: It seems now that I cannot edit the new object elements in input fields... What could be the case?

Comment: In input fields? I think you need to open a new question for that, since this one is answered.

Comment: I've created just now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49030668/assigned-object-elements-cannot-be-edited-in-component-javascript-vuejs

Comment: Lovely.. tricky part is objects inside the array also copied by reference. whoa

Comment: Thank you very much @Chris you saved my life :D