# Edited: assigned object elements cannot be edited in component javascript/vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a copy of the object using Object.assign function inside a method (thanks to @Chris advice) as below:
(It could be `quill-editor` or any other text input field)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <quill-editor
    v-model="itemsCopy[0].text"
    :options="editorOption"
    >
    </quill-editor> 
    {{itemsCopy[0].text}}
    <button @click="copyAndChange()"> </button>
  </div>
</template>


<script>


export default {
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
              {text: 'text1', active: true},
              {text: 'text1', active: true},
              {text: 'text1', active: true}
            ],
            itemsCopy [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        function copyAndChange() {
          this.itemsCopy = this.items.slice();
          for (var i=0; i<this.itemsCopy.length; i++) {
            var obj = Object.assign({}, this.itemsCopy[i]);
            obj.text = "something";
            this.itemsCopy[i] = obj;  //replace the old obj with the new modified one.
            console.log('text from items: ' + this.items[i].text)
            console.log('text from itemsCopy: ' + this.itemsCopy[i].text)
          }
          return 0
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Case1. I'm not running the function - all works

Case2. I'm running the function once - and I can see the "something" text within the editor, I can edit it, but the output inside `{{itemsCopy[0].text}}` are not changing...

After I run the function - I noticed I cannot edit the object's text field (and also active variable)

Comment: are you getting errors in console?

Comment: @F.bernal no, all is runnig as it should

Comment: do you have itemsCopy in s vue obj?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean...

Comment: see this example with your code.. (adapted) https://jsfiddle.net/tng9r8j3/99/

Comment: I'm checking...

Comment: @D.bernal Okay, as I can see, your example works, so I've got some kind of error... Not found yet.

Comment: @F.bernal I tried to find the reason why this is not working, but no with luck... I updated my question, maybe this will be something that will help to find the reason...

Comment: oh, I solved it... It should be as you wrote - declare new variable `itemsCopy=[]` inside the method (do not use `this.itemsCopy` inside the method `(!)` ), and after all iteration - just `return this.itemsCopy = itemsCopy`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you make a copy of `items` and don't do anything with that copy, from what I see.

Comment: yes, but If I'm trying to configure my editor `v-model="items[0].text"` it will output edited text into `{{items[0].text}}`, on new object it's now working. I don't know why..